# Remove header and add repeated headers to excel by Pandas

Tags: header

I have a excel file with multiple columns. I need to add repeatedly headers "Time_s", "Temp", and "Signal". columns A, B and C get "Time_s", "Temp", and "Signal" and then the rest of the columns are repeating as such. There are 21 columns with 200 rows of data.

I tried several ways but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following code did the job:

```
df_columns = list(df.columns)
col_list = df_columns[df_columns.index('B 11:34 time'):]
for i in range(0, len(col_list), 3):
     name = col_list[i]
     col_list[i] = 'Time [s]'
     col_list[i+1] = 'Temp. [C]'
     col_list[i+2] = 'Signal'

 df_columns[df_columns.index('B 11:34 time'):] = col_list
 df.columns = df_columns
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**